# Reuse Websocket Connection in shared WebWorker

Tags: sockets, websocket, web-worker

I am using Websocket communication in a shared WebWorker in Firefox. It works fine for "init" as you can see below, the client sends the site which was loaded in browser to server, the server responses some data. Now i would like to re-use the "socket" to send the id of a button which was clicked, but that does not work. See the "button" event. When using a new socket connection, it would work, but i would rather re-use the existing connection. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Main Thread:

```
function initCommWebWorker() {
    worker.port.start();
    worker.port.postMessage(["init", document.URL, HOST, PORT]);
}

function buttonclick(url, button) {

    worker.port.postMessage(["button", document.URL, HOST, PORT, button.id]);
...
```

Shared WebWorker:

```
self.addEventListener("connect", function(e) {

var port = e.ports[0];
var socket = null;

port.addEventListener("message", function (event) {

    switch (event.data[0]) {

    case "init":
        var server = "ws://" + event.data[2] + ":" + event.data[3];
        socket = new WebSocket(server);
        socket.onopen = function(){
            socket.send('{"site":"' + event.data[1] + '","type":"' + TYPE + '"}');
        };
        socket.onmessage = function(event) {
            port.postMessage(event.data);
        };
        socket.onclose = function(event) {
            port.postMessage('{"onclose":"' + event.data + '"}');
        };
        break;

    case "button":
        socket.send('{"button":"' + event.data[4] + '","type":"' + TYPE + '"}');
```

...

Comment: When you say doesn't work, what do you mean? Is there an error? Does the shared worker never even get the "button" message? Can you put some `console.log`s in to see where the code gets to?

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.10 with FireFox 36.0 no request reaches the Websocket server. I did some further testing with chromium on a Raspberry Pi and there it works fine. Pi is the target system, so from my point of view the issue could be closed.